# Create Dendrogram with Elki

Tags: java, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, elki

I want to plot a dendrogram for a cluster result. Right now I am using ElkiBuilder from ELKI 0.7.5 for clustering.

In the best case I'd like to directly plot a dendrogram.

If that's not possible I'd like to extract information (distances) from the clustering to create a dendrogram with another library (eg. using newick format)

Therefore my questions:

- Is it possible to create dendrograms with ELKI?
- Is it possible to access the distances which have been calculated during the clustering? (the distances used when two clusters were merged)

Right now I am using the following code for clustering:

```java
public Clustering<?> createClustering() {
    double[][] distanceMatrix = new double[][]{
            {0.0, 1.0, 3.0},
            {1.0, 0.0, 4.0},
            {3.0, 4.0, 0.0}
    };
    int noOfClusters = 2;
    // Adapter to load data from an existing array.
    DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(distanceMatrix);
    // Create a database (which may contain multiple relations!)
    Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
    // Load the data into the database (do NOT forget to initialize...)
    db.initialize();

    Clustering<?> clustering = new ELKIBuilder<>(CutDendrogramByNumberOfClusters.class) //
            .with(CutDendrogramByNumberOfClusters.Parameterizer.MINCLUSTERS_ID, noOfClusters) //
            .with(AbstractAlgorithm.ALGORITHM_ID, AnderbergHierarchicalClustering.class) //
            .with(AGNES.Parameterizer.LINKAGE_ID, WardLinkage.class)
            .build().run(db);
    return clustering;
}
```

Comment: The UI of ELKI can display a dendrogram. And obviously that needs the merging distances. So it **certainly is possible**. Maybe you just need to explore the library a bit more? The class `CutDendrogram...` likely uses the dendrogram, but by cutting returns a flat partitioning instead, so maybe that is not the class you wanted to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AGNES` class (instead I recommend to use `AnderbergHierarchicalClustering` instead, it is much faster but gives the exact same result) returns the clustering in a standard form called "pointer hierarchy" ([`PointerHierarchyRepresentationResult`](https://elki-project.github.io/releases/release0.7.5/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/hierarchical/PointerHierarchyRepresentationResult.html)). The merge of i and j at height h is represented as a pointer from i to j, with height h. Afterwards, j represents the merged cluster. This basic form was introduces by Sibson et al. with the SLINK algorithm in 1973.

In particular this contains the `y` information (`getParentDistanceStore`), the merges (given by `getParentStore`), and it can compute an order to arrange the points for visualization `getPositions`.

You may want to have a look at the code of [`DendrogramVisualization`](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/release0.7.5/addons/batikvis/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/visualization/visualizers/visunproj/DendrogramVisualization.java), which is responsible for creating the SVG dendrogram in the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To be honest I am not very experienced in programming so I am having trouble to understand how the library works.

- How can I get the PointerHierarchyRepresentationResult from my clustering variable?
- Do I only have to convert my settings from the gui to the ElkiBuilder to perform the same task (import distanceMatrix, run Anderberg , extract clusters and plot the dendrogram)? If yes, can you tell me how to do that or where I can find information on how to do that?
- Is it possible to add IDs to the leafs of the dendrogram?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Get it from the primary algorithm, not from the "cut" extraction algorithm. It likely attaches the pointer result as a child result, though, if you need both. I don't think current visualizers can add labels to the dendrogram, because that is not very scalable, and we're more interested in larger data where you couldn't read them anyway. But for small data sets this would be a nice feature to have.
In many cases it will be easier to use scripting to run ELKI from the command line, e.g. with `-resulthandler ExportVisualizations` than to "drive" a series of experiments from Java.

Comment: (Largely because scripting is easier than Java for such things, and ELKI can be very well run from command line scripts, Makefiles etc., using `java -jar elki.jar cli -dbc.in file -algorithm alg ...`)